# In iOS11 trying to add a round image as navigationItem in a NavigationBar and it is not clipping its edges

Tags: swift, rightbarbuttonitem, navigationitem, ios13.3

Using iOS13.3, XCode11.3,

I try to place a round Image as rightBarButtonItem on my largeTitle NavigationBar.

The button is drawn, however it does not get clipped and there are ugly corners in white remaining.

[image]

Here is my code (see below):

As you can see, I added the `clipsToBounds = true` to it - but I do not see the edges being clipped. Why ???

```swift
if let image = image {
    self.profileImage.image = image
} else {
    self.profileImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile-placeholder-small")
}

let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(self.profileImage.image, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.callMethod), for: .touchDragInside)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 36, height: 36)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton

button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36).isActive = true

self.profileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
self.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImage.frame.size.width / 2
self.profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
self.profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: this is background of button as I understood, change its background to clear, or change its cornerRadius and so on, as for profileImage

Comment: where you are adding profileImage ?

Comment: Thanks, Alexandr and JawadAli, for your inputs. I understand my error now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding button in `navigation bar` and setting `clipToBounds` to `profileImage` 
give corner radius to button instead of image will solve your issue.
Currently your button is of size 36x36

Comment: Thanks, JawadAli, for your input. I understand my error now.